# Change CSS based on a condition

Tags: php, html, css

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to change the CSS background color based on the selection of the PHP value.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
if (temp_value != '') {  <style>span.class_color = "#ccffcc";</style> }  
else { <style>span.class_color = "#ffffff" </style> } 
<span class="class_color">Hello there!</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

- Your CSS definition doesn't make any sense, span.class_color is the selector, if you want to assign the color of text the value then you'd need span.class_colour {color: #fff}.
- The last line is invalid PHP, I'm presuming you want to display it using echo or end php using ?> before that.

You can also simply define two classes in CSS like:

```
<style>
span.class_color_normal {
    color: #ccffcc;
}
span.class_color_empty {
    color #fff;
}
</style>
```

And then in PHP change class like:

```
if ($temp_value != '')
    $class = 'class_color_normal';
else
    $class = 'class_color_empty';
echo '<span class="', $class, '">your text here</span>';
```

Comment: That also did the trick.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For assigning the value to the css property, we must use `:` not `=`.

```
if (temp_value != '') {  echo '<style>span.class_color: "#ccffcc";</style>'; }  
else { echo '<style>span.class_color: "#ffffff" </style>'; } 

<span class="class_color">Hello there!</span>
```

Comment: @Kevin Davis Does it fix your problem?

Comment: You should be echoing the last line, or PHPing the first two lines? ;-)

Comment: @RacilHilan I'm sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: You're still mixing HTML and PHP codes together. You either need to change the last line to PHP like you did for the first two lines: `echo '<span class="class_color">Hello there!</span> '`, or you need to surround the first two lines with `<?php ....  ?>` tags.

Comment: Also CSS does not have a `span.class_color` property. It should be `span.class {color: xxx;}`.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind... I'm sorry for the brain fart..

What I should have done is this:

```
{ background-color: #ccffcc;}
```